# Is "x = new(Foo)" the same as "x = new Foo" for an arbitrary Foo?

Tags: c++, syntax, new-operator

I am looking at some legacy code and came across `x=new(Foo);` (note the parenthesis around the type supplied). I tested out variations and it appears to be the same as `x=new Foo;`

Foo is a non-POD data structure. Some external memory leak program is flagging the line - it's allocating memory for a CORBA out parameter so the caller should be taking care of the delete but that is a separate issue with many layers of indirection.

Is my analysis correct and is it acceptable style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the name of the type has parentheses it must be enclosed in parentheses. Other types may be enclosed as well.

Example where parentheses are required:

```
new int(*[10])();    // parser error: parsed as (new int) (*[10]) ()
new (int (*[10])()); // OK: allocates an array of 10 pointers to functions
```

From [cppreference.com: new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)

Answer (score 10):

It is correct, but the style is at least unusual.

Parentheses around a complete type name are sometimes allowed, but in this case are extraneous. It's like putting parentheses around an expression where not needed. Perhaps the closest analogy would be

```
return( 0 ); /* looks like a function, but isn't */
```

Confusingly, the parens are required for the `sizeof` operator, when passing it a type name but not when passing it an expression. Personally I see that as an inconsistency, and wouldn't choose to spread it to the rest of the language.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it turns out that it must be more subtle than that.  For example, the following code doesn't compile: `(int) main() { return 0; }`.

Comment: Not true, parentheses around types are not usually allowed.

Comment: @zch Then, is there a (without reference thumping, although I sense this coming) short list of when parenthesis *are* allowed around types?

Comment: @pst I don't know of any, this is first example I remember.

Comment: @zch indeed, I'm looking at the standard now and I can't actually find where the parentheses in `int (Foo)` appear in the grammar.

Comment: (… continued) I thought `new` might allow extra parens to discern the unparenthesized typename from the remainder of the expression, but instead it follows maximal munch. Hmm…

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Not sure what is the protocol to score this because both answers boil down to the same thing. But I gave the award to the other answer since it is shortest and the cppreference.com is new to me and a big help. Thanks All!!